# postfix/courier authorization failed

Tags: courier

I've tried to install postfix/courier with saslauthd with succes, but when i connect with my client i get the following

```
pop3d-ssl: couriertls: /etc/courier/pop3d.pem: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
```

can anyone help me out how to fix this problem :(

i followed this tutorial which asks at some point to erase the file that seems to be missing, yet I'm probably unable to use my new cert.

http://www.pixelinx.com/2010/10/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-and-amavis/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a file named `/etc/courier/pop3d.pem`.

Change `TLS_CERTFILE` in `/etc/courier/pop3d-ssl` to point your certificate.

Comment: I still get the following. I can confirm that I have a certificate in place. pop3d-ssl: couriertls: /var/lib/courier/couriersslcache: No such file or directory
pop3d-ssl: couriertls: /etc/courier/pop3d.pem: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory

Comment: @Ando I don't think you understand. The value for `TLS_CERTFILE` and the path to your certificate must be the same. Right now you are pointing to a file path that does not exist. Point it to the one that does. That is point it at your certificate.